# Name of object within another object

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I have a class called Prescriptions.  It has properties that are other classes.  So, for example, a property name of Fills would be from the PDInt class which has other properties about the value that I need.

If I want to set the value of the Fills property in the Prescription class it would be something like

`Prescription p = new Prescription();
p.Fills.Value = 33;`

So now I want to take the name of the Fills property and stuff it in a the tag property in a winform control.

```
this.txtFills.Tag = p.Fills.GetType().Name;
```

However when I do this, I get the base class of the property, not the property name.  So instead of getting "Fills", I get "PDInt".

How do I get the instantiated name of the property?

Thank you.

Comment: Just try googling "c# reflection property name", first hit http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-property-names/

Comment: Astander, thank you for the link, but this is not what I am looking for.  I don't want to have to reflect the parent class and iterate through it to find a single property.  I want to fill a group of edit controls with property names from my class and am looking for a way of taking a single property that is a class and getting it's instantiated name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) that I use it when I wanna work like you:

```
public static class ModelHelper
{
    public static string Item<T>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        if (expression.Body is MemberExpression)
        {
            return ((MemberExpression)(expression.Body)).Member.Name;
        }
        if (expression.Body is UnaryExpression)
        {
            return ((MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)(expression.Body)).Operand)
                    .Member.Name;
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

use it as :

```
var name = p.Item(x=>x.Fills);
```

For detail about how method works see [Expression Tree in .Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)

Comment: +1.  Dude, I can't believe you did that.  Perfect example of what I needed.  I have been seeing Expression Trees on the periphery for a while.  I am going to have to brush up on it and learn more.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Check this blogpost which is helpful : http://handcraftsman.wordpress.com/2008/11/11/how-to-get-c-property-names-without-magic-strings/

Do this you need to make USe of reflection feature of .net framework.

Something like this

```
Type type = test.GetType();

PropertyInfo[] propInfos = type.GetProperties();
for (int i = 0; i < propInfos.Length; i++) 
{
    PropertyInfo pi = (PropertyInfo)propInfos.GetValue(i);
    string propName = pi.Name;
}
```

Comment: U can use expression tree without reflection with more usable code.

Comment: blog post good, your example code bad (it's exactly what the blog author is trying to avoid)

Comment: Pranay, thanks for the answer.  What I was looking for was posted by Saeed above.

Answer (score 0):

You can get you like as this ? ↓

```
public class Prescription
{
    public PDInt Fills;
}

public class PDInt 
{
    public int Value;
}




Prescription p = new Prescription();
foreach(var x in p.GetType().GetFields())
{
    // var type = x.GetType();  // PDInt　or X //Fills
}
```

Comment: Scott, thanks for the example.   I don't want to have to reflect the parent class and iterate through it to find a single property. I want to fill a group of edit controls with property names from my class and am looking for a way of taking a single property that is a class and getting it's instantiated name.  Make sense?

Comment: @MikeMalter OH...yes, I'm sorry but I can catch you mean now... And I also found a Perfect example above.... Thank you~~